# Is time complexity the only thing to consider when trying to compare two codes in terms of terms their speed?

Tags: c, time-complexity, prime-factoring

Recently i wrote a code for finding primefactors of a number within the limits of "int" datatype in C. When i showed it to my friend he told that there are more optimised ways which have time complexities of O(sqrt(n)), O(log(n)). When I ran the code having time complexity O(sqrt(n)) and my code on Dev C++ i saw that the total time taken by both the codes was nearly the same. What is the time complexity of my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int k = 2, n, m;
    printf("enter a +ve integer greater than 1:- ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = n;
    do {
        if (n % k == 0) {
            n /= k;
            printf("%d,", k);
        }
        if (n == 1)
            break;
        while (n % k != 0) {
            if (k == 2)
                k = 3;
            else
                k += 2;
        }
    } while (n % k == 0);
    printf("prime factors of %d\n.", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what number did you try? 7? Change the int to long long int and factor 4611686014132420609 and it starts to feel.

Comment: You are testing `if (k == 2)` for every divisor candidate. Test for even numbers first. You might be interested in [Fast Prime Factorization Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756335/fast-prime-factorization-algorithm).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala i used the no. 1234567890.

Comment: 1234567890 = 2 × 3² × 5 × 3607 × 3803 so it is a really bad example

Comment: @AnttiHaapala now i understand it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The time-complexity analysis is made for the sake of *large N*. If you do not feel the effect yet, your N is not large enough. I changed the `%d`s to `%lld` and `int`s to `long long int` and factored the square of the Mersenne prime that Euler found, i.e. (2³¹-1)².

Results:

```
% echo 4611686014132420609 | time ./a.out
enter a +ve integer greater than 1:- 2147483647,2147483647,prime factors of 4611686014132420609
../a.out  12.15s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 12.154 total
% echo 4611686014132420609 | time factor
4611686014132420609: 2147483647 2147483647
factor  0.00s user 0.00s system 87% cpu 0.001 total
```

I.e. even when compiled with GCC and -O3, your program required at least 12000 times as much CPU power to factor the number than the `factor` program.